# Updating unique constraint index after deleting records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

So I've got a postgres database full of users

```
create_table :users do |t|
  t.string :subdomain
  t.index [:subdomain], name: "index_users_on_subdomain", unique: true, using: :btree
end
```

One of them deletes their account by mistake and wants to sign up again. But a validation error is called. Even though the record itself was deleted, the subdomain still exists in the index

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_users_on_subdomain"
```

This feels like a bug to me. Shouldn't the index be updated in the after_destroy callback? Am I expected to manually drop and add the index each time someone removes their account?

Any ideas?

Comment: If you suspect a bug it would be prudent to mention your version of Postgres.

Comment: Do you use some kind of soft-delete gem like `acts_as_paranoid` or `paranoia` that doesn't remove the user from the database, but just marks it as deleted?

Comment: @spickermann - That was my precise problem. I thought the records were being deleted, but it was indeed a soft delete. Using `destroy!` as opposed to `destroy` on my models has fixed the problem. Thanks for the insight!